# Setting build.gradle parameter via command line

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

When I build under some circumstances, I need bootJar.enabled to be false, and under other circumstances I need it to be true. I'd like to avoid having two build.gradle just for this (or some awkward sed injection).

So I thought I'd do the following in my build.gradle:

```
bootJar {
   if(project.hasProperty("doBootJar"))
   {
       println "found doBootJar: ${project.getProperty("doBootJar")}";
       enabled = project.getProperty("doBootJar);
   }
   else
   {
       println "default doBootJar";
       enabled = true;
   }
   println "enabled:  ${enabled}";
}
```

Then the idea was I can call either `gradle clean build` and enabled will be set to `true`, or `gradle -PdoBootJar="false" clean build` and enabled will be set to `false`, or `gradle -PdoBootJar="true" clean build` and enabled will be set to `true`.

Instead, the following output happens for each:

`gradle clean build`:
default doBootJar
enabled: true

`gradle -PdoBootJar="false" clean build`:
found doBootJar: false
enabled: true

`gradle -PdoBootJar="true" clean build`:
found doBootJar: true
enabled: true

So clearly the if/else is working, the property is found/unfound correctly, the value of the property is read in correctly when found, yet enabled is not set correctly.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `doBootJar` is a `String`, not a `Boolean`. So when you run:

```
gradle -PdoBootJar="false"
```

the property contains the `String` `'false'`.

You need to convert it to a `Boolean` somehow.

Given you want `enabled` to be `false` if and only if `doBootJar` is the `String` `'false'`, I suggest writing:

```
enabled = project.getProperty('doBootJar') != 'false'
```

Comment: Perfect!  That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a closing " in this line:

```
enabled = project.getProperty("doBootJar);
```

If it is not the case, please try using ext.

```
project.ext.doBootJar = project.hasProperty("doBootJar") ? project.getProperty("doBootJar").toBoolean() : true

bootJar {
  enabled = project.ext.doBootJar
  println "doBootJar: ${project.ext.doBootJar}"
  println "enabled: ${enabled}"
}
```

Comment: Sorry the machine the code lives on cannot connect to internet, so that was a retyped snipped.  I missed a closing ".